# Txtfile search not working

Tags: java, search, text-files

Ok so i have inputted a number of records to a text file and i can both write to and read from this file, but i am now attempting to search through this textfile and have encountered a problem.

```
package assignmentnew;

// Import io so we can use file objects
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SearchProp {
    public void Search() throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            String details, input, id, line;
            int count;
            Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please enter your housenumber: ");
            input = user.next();
            Scanner housenumber = new Scanner(new File("writeto.txt"));
            while (housenumber.hasNext())
            {
                id = housenumber.next();
                line = housenumber.nextLine();
                if (input.equals(id))
                {
                    System.out.println("House number is: "  + id + "and" + line);
                    break;
                }
                if(!housenumber.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("no house with this number");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("File failure");
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what value i enter i am told that the house number is not present in the file, but obviously it is, any ideas?

Addendum:

File Structure in textfile.

```
27,Abbey View,Hexham,NE46 1EQ,4,150000,Terraced
34,Peth Head,Hexham,NE46 1DB,3,146000,Semi Detached
10,Downing Street,London,sw19,9,1000000,Terraced
```

Comment: Can you give the structure of the house number files ?

Comment: how does the input file look like? (Paste it and format it as code in your question.)

Comment: Could it be that one of user.next() and housenumber.nextLine() have trailing whitespaces / line separator, and not the other ? Maybe a comparision that ignores whitespaces would help ...

Comment: i have pasted the file structure in the textfile under addendum, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default delimiter for a scanner is white-space, and not `,`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `housenumber.useDelimiter(",");` and the code will work.

**EDIT:**
Set it before the while.
And that is what I get for example for 27.

```
Please enter your housenumber: 
27
House number is: 27 and ,Abbey View,Hexham,NE46 1EQ,4,150000,Terraced
```

Comment: @Darren Burgess exactly what changes did you do to your code? I have put the useDelimeter just after ceation of the scanner and before the while loop, and that is waht I get, see EDIT in my answer.

Comment: i just removed the commas when entering my values into the textfield meaning that there was no need to change the delimiter of the scanner. Understand what you mean though, thanks